# Invertibility and comparison to zero in the MacNeille sections (bounded extended reals)

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

(The following three paragraphs are given for context.  Readers already aware of the terminology can skip to “the problem” below.)

In a spatial topos $\mathop{\textbf{Sh}}(X)$ the **MacNeille sections** (or MacNeille reals, MacNeille cuts, Dedekind-MacNeille reals, bounded extended reals, or a wealth of other confusingly similar terms) is the sheaf whose sections on $U\subseteq X$ open are pairs $(f_\flat,f_\sharp)$ of real-valued functions on $U$ such that $f_\flat(x) = \mathop{\textrm{lim.inf}}\limits_x f_\sharp$ and $f_\sharp(x) = \mathop{\textrm{lim.sup}}\limits_x f_\flat$ for each $x\in U$ (here $\mathop{\textrm{lim.inf}}\limits_x g$ stands for $\mathop{\textrm{sup}}\limits_{V\in\mathscr{V}(x)} \mathop{\textrm{inf}}\limits_{y\in V} g(y)$ with $\mathscr{V}(x)$ the neighborhood filter of $x$, and analogously for $\mathop{\textrm{lim.sup}}\limits_x g$; note that $f_\flat$ and $f_\sharp$ are then automatically lower and uppper semicontinuous respectively).

(Reference: P. Johnstone, *Sketches of an Elephant* (2002), section D.4.7, where the MacNeille reals are defined internally using cuts, and the definition of the previous paragraph appears as corollary D.4.7.5(ii).  Note that in A. S. Troelstra & D. van Dalen, *Constructivism in Mathematics* (1988), chapter 5, section 5, the same object, defined internally, is given the name “bounded extended reals”.  Further note that functions such as $(f_\flat,f_\sharp)$ are also known as (in our case, locally bounded) **normal uppper/lower semicontinuous**, see R. P. Dilworth, “The Normal Completion of the Lattice of Continuous Functions”, *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **68** (1950), 427–438.  Finally, note that from results in Kenneth Hardy's [1968 thesis “Rings of normal functions”](https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/concern/theses/c821gk58m), 1.20–1.24, summarized in K. Hardy, “On normal functions”, *General Topology and Appl.* **2** (1972), 157–163, prop. 2.2, if $X$ is a Baire space, a normal function pair $(f_\flat,f_\sharp)$ can also be represented as an element of the inductive limit over all dense $G_\delta$ sets $W \subseteq U$ of the set of continuous real-valued functions on $W$ with the obvious restriction maps; we need to add “locally bounded” everywhere to agree with the object defined above, but I believe this is no problem, and clearly irrelevant to my question.)

The strict order on the MacNeille sections is (I think!) given by $(f_\flat,f_\sharp) < (g_\flat,g_\sharp)$ (on $U\subseteq X$ open) iff $f_\sharp(x) < g_\flat(x)$ for each $x \in U$.  Addition and multiplication are *not* given by pointwise operations on $f_\flat,f_\sharp$, but when $X$ is a Baire space they can be defined by restricting to a dense $G_\delta$ on which the function is continuous (see reference to Hardy in previous paragraph) and then performing pointwise operations on this restriction.

**The problem:** P. Johnstone, *Sketches of an Elephant*, proposition D.4.7.10(i), claims that if $f$ is a MacNeille section which is invertible, then $f>0$ or $f<0$ holds in $\mathop{\textbf{Sh}}(X)$ (which means externally that $X$ is covered by an open set on which the restriction of $f$ is $>0$ and an open set on which the restriction of $f$ is $<0$).  I believe this is incorrect, and a counterexample is provided by $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ the “step” function taking the value $-1$ on the negative reals and $+1$ on the positive reals (at $0$ we have $f_\flat(0)=-1$ and $f_\sharp(0)=+1$, at all other points they coincide): this MacNeille section satisfies $f^2=1$ identically (so it is certainly invertible), but the open set where $f>0$ consists of the positive reals, the open set where $f<0$ consists of the negative reals, and they do not cover $X=\mathbb{R}$.

**Questions:** Is my counterexample correct¹ and is the statement in the Elephant indeed flawed?  If so, is there a correct statement that is analogous, or should we simply disregard this?  (I believe a correct statement is that $f$ is invertible iff $|f|>0$, where $|f| = \mathop{\textrm{sup}}\limits ( f,-f ) $.)

1. The main reason I have doubts is that I'm not sure I correctly translated the definition of the strict order on the MacNeille sections, defined internally, into the relation on the pair of normal semicontinuous functions above, or that I have the right multiplication, but on this example I fail to see what else it could be.

**Meta:** I hesitate on how to tag this question.  I'm giving it the “topos-theory” and “constructive-mathematics” because it's about a statement in the *Elephant* and the validity of a statement that can be formulated in constructive math, but you can also make the case that it's a question about rings of continuous and semicontinuous functions on a topological space.  Feel free to add another tag if you feel strongly about this.

Comment: You example "step" function (with 0/1 instead of -1/+1) is even given as a first example of a MacNeille section which is not a Dedekind section on p. 1018 of the Elephant...

Answer (score 5):

I think there is something wrong with the arithmetic operations on the MacNeille reals as defined in the *Elephant*, even with the "straightforward" addition (see p. 1021): Let $f$ be your "step function" example of a MacNeille section defined on $X = \mathbb{R}$. The truth value of $q < f$ (for $q$ a rational number) is $\mathbb{R}$ for $q < -1$, $]0, \infty[$ for $-1 \le q < 1$ and $\varnothing$ for $1 \le q$. Consider also the MacNeille section $-f$ (negation works fine). Then the truth value of $-1 < f + (-f)$ is by definition of $+$ obtained by taking the union over all $p + q = 1$ of the intersection of the truth values of $p < f$ and $q < -f$. If I am not mistaken, this turns out to be $\left]-\infty, 0\right[ \cup \left]0, \infty\right[$. Then $f + (-f)$ is not globally equal to $0$. And in fact, since the truth value of $f + (-f) < 0$ is $\varnothing$, this $f + (-f)$ does not fulfill the locatedness axioms on a MacNeille real from p. 1015, of which a special case is $\lnot (f + (-f) < 0) \Longrightarrow -1 < f + (-f)$.

Comment: I hope I am not talking nonsense here, it is quite late. ;-)

Comment: You're right! Thanks for pointing this out, Johnstone's definition of addition is flawed for the MacNeille reals, and probably corresponds to naïvely adding $f_♭$ and $f_♯$, which doesn't work (it only gives the right result on a dense open set). A correct definition needs some “$¬¬$” sprinkled in the right places as can be seen by comparing theorems 6.2 and 6.5 of chapter 5 of Troelstra & van Dalen.

Comment: (Probably the best way to define the “extended”/“classical” reals in a topos $\mathcal{T}$ is as the object of Dedekind reals in the topos $\mathcal{T}_{¬¬}$ of sheaves for the $¬¬$ topology on $\mathcal{T}$, which can then be seen as an object in $\mathcal{T}$, with addition, multiplication, etc., coming from $\mathcal{T}_{¬¬}$. The “bounded extended” or “MacNeille” reals are then just those which are bounded between two rationals.)